# Set up rails routes based on associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have (2) models Item and Item_Type.

Item has_one :item_type

The item_type schema:

```
  create_table "item_types", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "item_id" <---
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I want to set up a route like so `/:item_type.title/` and showcase all the items associated with that item_type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume item titles are unique. Also, the way your schema is set up, each item type can only have one item, so you'd need to refactor that if you want to have more than one item show up for a particular item type.

Something like this would work:

```
# routes.rb
get '/:title' => 'items#item_by_type_title
```

This will make e.g. yourserver.com/foo route to the action 'item_by_type_title' on ItemsController. Then, in your items controller:

```
def item_by_type_title
  @item_type = ItemType.find_by_title(params[:title])
  @item = @item_type.item
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! How would you refactor the association? I was trying to avoid :item_type has_many :items

Comment: @Dileet, the only way for item_types to be associated with many items is if the item types has_many items (a one-to-many database association, in which each item would have an item_type_id), or a many-to-many relationship. It really depends on your intentions.